# How to simulate $http timeout in Jasmine and Angular

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to simulate http timeout using Jasmine. I have created an Angular HTTPInterceptor

```
angular.module('coreErrorHandler')
.factory('HTTPTimeoutInterceptorService', function($rootScope, $q, AppConfig) {
    return {
        'request': function(config) {
            config.timeout = 2000;
            return config;
        }
    };
});
```

And I have added the service to $httpProvider

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('HTTPTimeoutInterceptorService');
```

The code works 100%, I am just not sure how to test it using Jasmine.

```
it('should wait for the timeout to elapse and issue an HTTP timeout error', function() {
    $httpBackend.when("GET", "http://google.com").respond({});
    var httpGetValue = $http.get("http://google.com");

    setTimeout(function(){
      $timeout.flush();
      console.log(httpGetValue);
      expect(SOMETHING).toEqual(false);
    }, 2100);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `setTimeout` here, you have to pass an argument to `$timeout.flush()` to simulate how long the time has passed.

```
it('should wait for the timeout to elapse and issue an HTTP timeout error', function() {
    $httpBackend.when("GET", "http://google.com").respond({});
    var httpGetValue = $http.get("http://google.com");

    $timeout.flush(2100); // specify how long to simulate here
    console.log(httpGetValue);
    expect(SOMETHING).toEqual(false);
});
```

Also see: [$timeout in ngMock documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your recommendation but it is still not triggering the timeout interceptor.